# Difference between copy/migrate/export in SQL developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL developer, it has the following tools, 
DATABASE copy, DATABASE export and Migrate.
I want to move one schema and all the data in it from one server to another. 
What is the difference between these options? Does anything serve what I am looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database Copy is probably what you want.

Supply two database connections, and we'll take objects and data and copy them from one database to another.

However, if your schema is large, this will be inefficient. The Copy routine does inserts, row-by-row across the jdbc connections.

Database Export takes the objects and data and offloads them to flat files. These flat files could then be used later to put in another database.

Migrate is used to take a database from SQL Server, Sybase, Teradata, Redshift, DB2, etc. to Oracle. It has an online (jdbc row-by-row) data copy and an offline (flat files for SQL Loader) data move mode. For SQL Server/Sybase, we can also translate the T-SQL stored procedures to PL/SQL.

Your solution might also lie elsewhere - Data Pump. We have a wizard for that as well, and works great for very large schemas/databases. You'll just need access to the database OS so you can put the DMP files into a Database Directory.